# Cramers Theorem for sum of Mixed Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have a sequence of random variables $$X_{1},...,X_{n}$$ that are iid Exp(1) and $$Y_{1},...,Y_{n}$$ that are iid Poisson(1). All are mutually independent.

We define: $$S_{n} = \sum_{k=1}^{n}W_{i}$$ such that

\begin{align}
W_{i} = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 
                X_{i} & \hspace{5mm} wp=1/2 \\
                Y_{i} & \hspace{5mm} wp=1/2 \\
                \end{array} \right.
\end{align}

I want to find $$P(\frac{S_{n}}{n}\gt c)$$

My Attempt:

$$M_{W}(t) = \frac{1}{2}M_{X}(t) + \frac{1}{2}M_{X}(t) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-t} + \frac{1}{2}e^{e^{t}-1}$$
$$\Lambda_{W}(t)=log(M_{W}(t)) = log(\frac{1}{2(1-t)})+log(2) + e^{t}-1$$
$$\Lambda_{W}^{*}(t) = sup_{t}[tx-\Lambda_{W}(t)]\implies\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(tx-\Lambda_{W}(t)) = 0$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}(tx-\Lambda_{W}(t))=x-e^{t}+\frac{1}{t-1} = 0$$

Now I am stuck. I cannot solve for max t.

I would then need to plug this into $$\Lambda_{W}^{*}(t_{max})$$
to get the result $$P(\frac{S_{n}}{n}\gt c)\leq e^{-n \Lambda_{W}^{*}(c)}$$

Comment: Why are you using moment-generating functions? I might suggest Markov's inequality, or if that doesn't suffice, then Chernoff bounds.

Comment: YOu want to compute exactly that probability? Or some bound ? Or some asympotics?